# Applescript: make new folder structure if it doesn't exist

Tags: macos, applescript

I've been searching through message boards trying to figure out how to execute this script. Essentially the goal is to be able to run this script while inside a folder and if certain folders do not exist, these folders would then be created. If they do already exist, nothing happens. Here's what I've cobbled together so far:

```
property archivesFolder : "Archives"

property imagesFolder : "Images"

property proofreadFolder : "Proofreading"

property proofFolder : "Proofs"

property sourceFolder : "Source"

try

tell application "Finder" to set theLocation to (folder of the front window as alias)

end try

tell application "Finder"

    if (exists folder archivesFolder) then
        (* do nothing *)
    else
        make new folder at theLocation with properties {name:archivesFolder}
    end if

    if (exists folder imagesFolder) then
        (* do nothing *)
    else
        make new folder at theLocation with properties {name:imagesFolder}
    end if

    if (exists folder proofreadFolder) then
        (* do nothing *)
    else
        make new folder at theLocation with properties {name:proofreadFolder}
    end if

    if (exists folder proofFolder) then
        (* do nothing *)
    else
        make new folder at theLocation with properties {name:proofFolder}
    end if

    if (exists folder sourceFolder) then
        (* do nothing *)
    else
        make new folder at theLocation with properties {name:sourceFolder}
    end if

end tell
```

What am I doing wrong ? (forgive my n00b code formatting, at work and can't figure out how to create code blocks) Also, is it possible to this not just on the front window, but on a folder that is just selected? Any help given would be awesome.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest two options (to run the script):

**Option 1**: Take that code (assuming it does what you plan), and save it as an application (with Script Editor).

Then, just drag that application to your window toolbar (you need to have the toolbar visible). To do that, hold the command key while dragging.

**Option 2**: Use Butler: http://manytricks.com/butler/
(there is a free version, I don't know your OSX version).

It allows you to define system-wide shortcut keys for applescript scripts.

Create a smart item (applescript); paste the code there, and in the name of the script add the shortcut keys: example: `create folder here ⇧⌥⌘N`

**EDIT:**

According to your comment, I understand your problem and I can tell you that you were missing the path (the current folder, in your case `theLocation`)

So, in every case of `if (exists folder archivesFolder) then` you need to add the `of theLocation` like this: `if not (exists folder archivesFolder of theLocation) then`

Finally, knowing that you won't do any thing if the folder exists, just test the false case.

I tested this code and am posting it here:

```
property archivesFolder : "Archives"

property imagesFolder : "Images"

property proofreadFolder : "Proofreading"

property proofFolder : "Proofs"

property sourceFolder : "Source"

try

    tell application "Finder" to set theLocation to (folder of the front window as alias)

end try

tell application "Finder"

    if not (exists folder archivesFolder of theLocation) then
        make new folder at theLocation with properties {name:archivesFolder}
    end if

    if not (exists folder imagesFolder of theLocation) then
        make new folder at theLocation with properties {name:imagesFolder}
    end if

    if not (exists folder proofreadFolder of theLocation) then
        make new folder at theLocation with properties {name:proofreadFolder}
    end if

    if not (exists folder proofFolder of theLocation) then
        make new folder at theLocation with properties {name:proofFolder}
    end if

    if not (exists folder sourceFolder of theLocation) then
        make new folder at theLocation with properties {name:sourceFolder}
    end if

end tell
```

Comment: I actually have it set up as Option 1 right now and it works fine if there is nothing in the folder. But if I delete one of those folders, it breaks the code and it does nothing. I'm wanting it to work in situations where not all the folders are present, but some may already be there (which happens depending on who set the original folder up).

Comment: @user1231499 here you go! if this worked for you, please approve the answer.

Comment: And like magic, it works. I thought there might be some kind of path needed for each if case, but I think I just tried something like adding "at theLocation" and stopped when that didn't work. Thank you very much, this will be great!

Actually, there wouldn't happen to be a way to set this up so that if you simply have the folder selected it would run, or is it really only feasible if the folder is in the open window?

Comment: Nevermind, just change out "try ... end try" argument to:

try
 tell application "Finder" to set theLocation to the selection as alias
end try

Comment: @user1231499 nice one! if it worked, please accept the answer in the green tick next to it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a shell script with [mkdir](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mkdir.1.html), since the option to create intermediate folders won't error if the folder already exists.

```
#  define a list of folders - items will need to be quoted if they contain spaces, etc.
property theFolders : {"Archives", "Images", "ProofReading", "Proofs", "Source"} -- can also nest, e.g. "Inside/One"

try
    tell application "Finder" to set targetFolder to (target of the front window) as alias
on error -- no window
    set targetFolder to (choose folder)
end try

# build a parameter string from the folder list
set {tempTID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, space}
set {theFolders, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {theFolders as text, tempTID}

do shell script "cd " & quoted form of POSIX path of targetFolder & "; mkdir -p " & theFolders
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tell application "Finder"
set theLocation to (target of front window) as string
set folderNames to {"archivesFolder", "imagesFolder", "proofreadFolder", "proofFolder", "sourceFolder"}
repeat with theFolder in folderNames
    try
        make new folder at theLocation with properties {name:"" & theFolder & ""}
    end try
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a script I did to sort a bunch of medical files into subfolders based on the date of service (explaining the "text 5 thru 14" in the script; the files are named according to a pattern so the script can extract the date of service from the filename). Rather than check if the folder already exists, I just put the make folder instruction in a try block; if the folder already exists, the 'try' fails, but the script continues under the assumption that the folder already exists. Using the 'text' item instead of 'character' returns the extracted string as a single string and not as an array of characters that have to be converted back into a string.

```
tell application "Finder"
set theDirectory to "Internal Disk:Users:steven:Documents:Vondalee:Medical"
set theFiles to every file in folder theDirectory whose name extension is "pdf"
repeat with eachFile in theFiles
    set theFileName to the name of eachFile
    set theFolder to text 5 thru 14 of theFileName
    try
        make new folder at theDirectory with properties {name:theFolder}
    end try
    move eachFile to folder theFolder of folder theDirectory
end repeat
end tell
```